# How to download files from a website with Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I'm not very familiar with Azure functions but am trying to learn and explore how to download files from a website using a time triggered function. I have the following code:

```
namespace PracticeFunction
{
    public static class PracticeFunction 
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFile("https://examplewebsite.com/file.zip", "zipfile");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function executes 'successfully' but the file doesn't seem to have downloaded anywhere. I am sure I am missing something very obvious but could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are these supposed to be [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/)? Please tag your appropriately. Just calling it a function isn't specific enough, as that word has a lot of meaning besides Azure Functions.

Comment: Yes, apologies @mason I have updated

Comment: Are you executing this code in the cloud? Generally you wouldn't just download a file to disc....you might load it into Azure Blob Storage or into memory and then process it somehow. See [Storage Considerations in Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations).

Comment: yes @mason that is my overall goal but for now I just want to see if I can complete this step - as I said I am very new to functions. Thank you :)

Comment: If you want to verify it downloaded, you do something like `log.LogInformation("File Exists: " + System.IO.FileExists("zipfile")`. Of course, that's rather pointless. If the code runs without exception, then you can be sure it downloaded to the location you specified.

Comment: thanks @mason - to clarify, it is possible to upload the file straight from the website to blob storage?

Comment: Depends on what kind of API's the blob storage system exposes. You could always use [WebClient.DownloadData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddata?view=netcore-3.1) to obtain a byte array representing the file, then immediately load that byte array into blob storage. Depends on the size of the file you're working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
client.DownloadFile("https://examplewebsite.com/file.zip", "zipfile");
```

The file is downloaded in a file named `zipfile` in your executable's folder, which is probably in your solution folder, in `bin` and then a couple more folders deep depending on your build configuration.